# Adding Numpy Arrays in python using np.sum?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The title basically explains it, I'm new to arrays and I need to add the columns, here is my array:

```
[[20,40,60,21,70]
[2,76,5,90,50]
[21,67,99,33,49]]
```

So I need to add (20 + 2 + 21), (40 + 76 + 67) etc..

I tried using np.sum but I'm somewhat new to arrays so I'm not sure how to slice/ index properly with arrays.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axis=0` in the sum function:

```
a = np.arange(15).reshape(-1,5)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
np.sum(a, axis=0)
# array([15, 18, 21, 24, 27])
```